# syntax error in wercker file when using wercker login command

Tags: docker, vagrant, wercker

I'm using `vagrant` to host my `docker` environment. I'm following the instructions on the `wercker` install page and when I type `wercker login`, I get the following...
`/usr/local/bin/wercker: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("`

Answer (score 0):

It did not work when I typed `vagrant ssh` first. If I only typed `vagrant up` and then `wercker login` it seems to work.

I guess I'm not totally clear on what `vagrant ssh` does. I thought it was necessary to develop inside the vagrant VM?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explication :
Before login into your vagrant virtual machine, you have to boot the Vagrant environment with : `vagrant up` and only after you will be able to SSH into your virutal machine with :  `vagrant ssh`.
This command allow you to log in into the virtual machine and work on it. That's all. But it's not required to log into the vagrant machine to works with because vagrant have a [sync folder feature](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/synced_folders.html).

To finish, check that the wercker-cli is installed in your vagrant virtual machine or on your host machine. I don't know where do you execute it.

I recommend you to check the [official vagrant documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/up.html) for more details.